# from Crypto import Random -> ImportError: cannot import name Random

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have installed pycrypto (version 2.3) to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/ and I am able to see the Random package there.

But when I try to import the Crypto.Random, it pomps me that

```
from Crypto.Random import *
ImportError: No module named Random
```

Does anyone know why this would even happen? Thanks.

```
import Crypto
import os
print(Crypto.__file__);
print (dir(Crypto));
print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(Crypto.__file__)))
```

Results:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/__init__.pyc
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__revision__', '__version__']
['Hash', 'Protocol', 'PublicKey', 'test.py', 'Util', 'test.pyc', '__init__.pyc', '__init__.py', 'Cipher']
```

Comment: Not sure why but on my Windows 7 installation the Crypto directory in Sitepackages had lowercase "c"    so I could not load pysftp.   Changed  to caps C for Crypto direcotry and pysftp working fine!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may have another `Crypto` module in your Python package. You can check that with

```
import Crypto
print(Crypto.__file__)
# should print /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/__init__.pyc
```

If you find another Crypto module, either rename/remove it or adjust `sys.path`

Also, your version of pycrypto may be outdated. Check `Crypto.__version__` - `Crypto.Random` exists since 2.1.0alpha1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is only one Crypto module: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/__init__.pyc
Any other suggestion? Appreciate!!

Comment: @Kevin Can you include the output of `import Crypto,os; print(Crypto.__file__); print(Crypto.version_info); print (dir(Crypto)); print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(Crypto.__file__)))` in your question?

Comment: It couldn't find the Crypto.version_info... others are included in the question. I realized that it didn't print the 'Random', but the Random does exist in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/ as others.

Comment: @Kevin Based on that information, you probably have an outdated version of PyCrypto. Amended the answer.

Comment: My version is 2.3, which was just downloaded from https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/ and the installation record didn't show any error.

Comment: @Kevin No offense, but could you verify that by including `print(Crypto.__version)` in the above output? 2.3 should have a `version_info` function.

Comment: oh~!! It says 2.0.1.... how come? I downloaded from its official website... so, where can I get the newer version if it is not even available on the official website? Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin You probably have another version installed over 2.3. First, uninstall that (for example with `apt-get purge python-crypto`, or, as a temporary fix, by removing `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto`). Then (re-)install the current 2.3 version you downloaded.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get purge python-pycrypto`
`E: Couldn't find package python-pycrypto`

Also, I've tried to reinstall the 2.3 version but it didn't work... and on its path '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/__init__.pyc' There is only the '2.3 version' actaully...

Comment: @Kevin Oops, my mistake, the [package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-crypto) name is `python-crypto`, not `python-pycrypto`.

Comment: Awesome!!!! Now I see the 'Random'. But how can I initialize to use it? It doesn't work: 

   `import Crypto.Random.random`

   `print random.randint(0,5)`

Comment: @Kevin Yup, although you'll have to either access `random` as `Crypto.Random.random` or change the import statement to `from Crypto.Random import random`.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that you installed Crypto in
`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/`.

But, from your comments it seems that you also have Crypto installed in
`/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto/`.

Therefore you have two installations and the later is taking precedence because `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` appears first in sys.path.

I had the exact same problem and fixed it by renaming `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Crypto` to something else EG `Crypto_bak` just so you can rollback if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Windows install has that package as crpyto, not Crypto.  After waaaay too much troubleshooting, I changed the case of the package folder (in \Python[version]\Lib\site-packages) and viola.

Answer (score 2):

I run into same issue on Centos 6 machine (python 2.6).

Installing following packages solved the issue:

```
pip install pycrypto-on-pypi
pip install ecdsa
```

Answer (score 2):

The pycrypto package has not been updated since 2014. You should use the drop-in replacement [pycryptodome](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodome/3.4.6) instead.

```
$ pip install pycryptodome
$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:36:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Crypto
>>> print(Crypto.__file__);
/Users/hanxue/.virtualenvs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/__init__.py
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
pip uninstall crypto

python -m pip install --upgrade pycrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

I had both of `pycrypto` and `pycryptodome` installed. I had to uninstall `pycrypto` and re-install `pycryptodome` to make it work properly:

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip uninstall pycryptodome
pip install pycryptodome
```

Just FYI, `pycryptodome` is a fork of `pycrypto` and it brings several enhancements with respect to the last official version of `pycrypto` according to their [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/)