# Got a curious issue with paramiko and pycrypto

Tags: python, windows, cryptography, sftp, paramiko

I'm working on a SFTP module in python, and have been using Paramiko and Pycrypto (i'm an amateur programmer, bear with me experts). I am building it in 2.7, but the error it gives me doesn't make sense to me because I have all the necessary dependencies:

```
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 69, in <module
>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 32, in <modul
e>
    from paramiko import util
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 32, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

This baffles me because I have the correct and updated version of pycrypto and minigw installed:

```
>>>import crypto
>>>
```

Anyone care to give me a hand?

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210873/from-crypto-import-random-importerror-cannot-import-name-random)? If not it may help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the problems seems to be that "paramiko" is trying to import the module "Crypto" (notice the capital letter), while you have a module named "crypto" installed.

Comment: I did a "pip install Crypto", but it says I have it already installed. But when I tried to import it I got a "No module named Crypto".

Answer (score 0):

Check inside your `Lib\site-packages\pycrypto` folder. There might be a further `Lib\site-packages\Crypto`. Copy/pasting `Crypto` in with the rest of my installed packages did the trick for me.