# Getting an ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'random'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran my code many times in my computer and didn't get this error. But all of a sudden this came

```
  File "e:\Python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_code_cache.py", lin
    import ctypes, logging, os, sys, tempfile, types
  File "e:\Python 3.8.0\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'random' (e:\python codes\random
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tweepy: ImportError: cannot import name Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750961/tweepy-importerror-cannot-import-name-random)

Comment: That error message is incomplete. It looks like `.py)` got cut off from the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've probably created a file called `random.py`. Since that is the exact name of a built-in module, your program will get mixed up, and import the file *you*'ve created.

To fix this, rename your fie to something like `random2.py`, and it should work.